# How to change data-sap-ui-theme of Certain control SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I've set them of my sapui5 application data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize_plus" but for listview I want to change the theme  to data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize". Is it possible to change theme for certain control ?

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The theme parameter is across the application.

But nevertheless you can achieve this using [UI Theme Designer.](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/a1/18094264684230bb6510045b5b5b7c/content.htm)
You can read more here [SAP Fiori Theme designer Wiki](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Fiori/SAP+Fiori+-+UI+Theme+Designer)

These designs will be applied across all the applications.

If you don't want to deal with designer and you are good at CSS then override the specific CSS classes accordingly and add that Custom CSS to your application. [Read more here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796.html)